# Software for converting bulk PSDs to JPEGs?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation, image-quality, batch-processing, file-size

I have a bulk of working PSDs and I want to convert them to JPEGs. It will take a long time to convert those PSDs to JPEGs using Photoshop by dragging each into it.

So I searched in Google and I found a software to for bulk conversion called *Sage Thumbs*. After converting a PSD to JPEG using this software, the file size is 530 kb, but when I use Photoshop to convert PSD to JPEG the file size is 2 MB.

The two images seem to be the same, but I can’t see any lower image quality in Sage Thumbs’s image. Should I proceed to use it to convert PSDs to JPEGs? Am I correct with my decision? Or is any other software to convert bulk PSD to JPEG without losing any image quality?

Comment: You should be asking yourself. "Am I okay with producing low resolution or low quality work?" The answer is hopefully NO

Comment: First off, what is the whole point of converting them? What is your end game? If you do need to convert a bunch of PSDs into JPGs, then perhaps you should looking into creating an "Action" within PS to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop can automate a batch script that will process the images natively, giving you full control over the resolution and compression of the saved files.

Comment: THANKS @13ruce. JUST CAME TO KNOW ABOUT ADOBE BRIDGE  [link](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just flow simple steps and you get low size JPEGs no need extra software for that.

Step 1: Create/Record Action in Photoshop.

Step 2: Must save your file in "File Menu -> Save for Web" or use "Shift + Alt + Ctrl + S".

Step 3: Save for Web Popup/Dialog box set JPEG and Quality: 60.

Step 4: Then stop action recording.

Step 5: Now close all files and goto File Menu -> Automate -> Batch select.

Step 6: Batch Dialog: Select your action in "Set or Action" dropdown.

Setp 7: Source: "Folder" -> Choose your bulk "PSDs" and Select ok button (If have subfolder then also select subfolder option)

Let me know if not getting any point or flow i will send images for each steps.

Answer (score 0):

Bridge is definitely the tool for this. Select your original files, right click, export to hard drive and you get a bunch of options on how to scale, resolution, etc.